# how to convert/transform an HTML table tbody (with rowspans) TO json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-table

I have an HTML table with combined row td's, or how to say, I don't know how to express myself (I am not so good at English), so I show it! This is my table:

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>line</th>
            <th>value1</th>
            <th>value2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">1</td>
            <td>1.1</td>
            <td>1.2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1.3</td>
            <td>1.4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">2</td>
            <td>2.1</td>
            <td>2.2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2.3</td>
            <td>2.4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

(you can check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QGfEN/))

I want to convert this table to a JSON variable by jquery or javascript.
How should it look like, and how should I do it? Thank you, if you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert only text use this one :

```
var array = [];

$('table').find('thead tr').each(function(){
    $(this).children('th').each(function(){
      array.push($(this).text());
    })
}).end().find('tbody tr').each(function(){
    $(this).children('td').each(function(){
      array.push($(this).text());
    }) 
})

var json = JSON.stringify(array);
```

Comment: This isn't really a representation of the table. It just generates a one-dimensional array of all values in the table. See http://jsfiddle.net/perqa/4E2L6/

Answer (score 1):

To make a somehow representation of your table made no problem to me, but the problem is how to parse it back to HTML! Here a JSON with the first 6 tags:

```
{"table":{"border":1,"thead":{"th":{"textContent":"line","tr":"textContent":"value1",...}}}}}...
```

OR for better understanding:

```
{"tag":"table","border":1,"child":{"tag":"thead","child":{"tag":"th","textContent":"line",
   "child":{"tag":"tr","textContent":"value1","child":...}}}}...
```

Closing tags are included.

For further explanations I need to know whether your table is a string or part of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I belive this is what you want:

```
var jsonTable = {};

// add a new array property named: "columns"
$('table').find('thead tr').each(function() {
    jsonTable.columns = $(this).find('th').text();
};

// now add a new array property which contains your rows: "rows"
$('table').find('tbody tr').each(function() {
    var row = {};

    // add data by colum names derived from "tbody"

    for(var i = 0; i < jsonTable.columnsl.length; i++) {
        row[ col ] = $(this).find('td').eq( i ).text();
    }

    // push it all to the results..

    jsonTable.rows.push( row );
};

alert(JSON.stringify(jsonTable));
```

I think there should be some corrections, but this is it I think.

Comment: I got this exception: `Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference` for this part: `jsonTable.rows.push(row);`

Comment: thanks for helping, but there are some problem: 1: `jsonTable.columns = $(this).find('th').text();` this means it will find all the `th`s, and create a big string with them; 2: `jsonTable.columnsl.length;` will be the big string's length